# Import-Module stops working sporadically

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-debugging, import-module

I have a problem where `Import-Module -Name "./MyAssembly.dll"` stops working sporadically. If I restart the computer, everything seems to work as normal for a while, but it's getting really frustrating.

The reason for importing the same module (in different Powershell sessions) is because I'm currently writing a cmdlet using C#, and I start a powershell instance as part of debugging the cmdlet.

The Import-Module command gives me no feedback whatsoever of whether or not the loading succeeded.

```
PS C:\Source\MyProject> Import-Module -Name "./MyAssembly.dll"
PS C:\Source\MyProject> Get-Stuffz
Get-Stuffz : The term 'Get-Stuffz' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or ope
rable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again
.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-Stuffz
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Get-Stuffz:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Any help or suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Perhaps do some verbose output (with checks if `stdout` is available) in your DLL to ever find out what part of importing failed. There are other possible reasons like remains of "DLL Hell" which Powershell cannot handle, so that it (or its manifest parser) attempts to load your newly compiled DLL with old cached manifests, hits a checksum mismatch and drops the attempt to import the module. Or, you've broken importing in your DLL's sources. Too hard to tell without in-depth debugging.

Comment: Great feedback! When I add the `-Verbose` switch to the Import-Module I can see that it imports one (of three) cmdlets. Very strange, but there must be an explaination for this.